# App crashes when I click on ocean or sea to get city name in maps

Tags: android, google-maps, indexoutofboundsexception

Error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0.
```

This is my code.

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            Geocoder geocoder;

            geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
                String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

                if (city == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Please select proper location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "" + city, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

       }
    });
```

Comment: Where is your code which is crashing at sea or ocean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Post your code... your LogCat.... I don't know... something...

Comment: You are trying to get a element from an array which has no elements.

Comment: @CamelCaseCoder: This is an IndexOutOfBoundException, not a NullPointerException

Comment: @Opiatefuchs the question got updated. Although it's along the same lines where code is try to access value from objects that don't contain any value. It's a simple case of handling the failure situations.

Comment: holding no values is not the same as not initialized or rather a "null" object.

Answer (score 1):

`GeoCoder` might not return a result in all cases, since a sea or ocean might not have an address.

In this case the list of results called `addresses` will have 0 items, but you still try to access to first item.

You should do something like this:

```
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
if (addresses.size() == 0) { 
    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Please select proper location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
// ... rest of the code
```